# Error while trying to connect Android to MySQL database using JDBC

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc, connection

I wrote a simple application in Android which consists of a button that,when clicked,tries to connect to a MySQL database using JDBC.
Now,i tried to enter the URL and credentials of a database located on the internet,and I was able to connect to it.

When i try to connect to the MySQL database i installed on my PC,it throws an SQLException regarding (i think) the JDBC string.
I used the root credentials for the access,in this way:

### jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name

I also tried to run the connection in a Java Application,and it runs fine...it has some sort of problem in Android.
There's the code of my application:

```
       package com.example.testconnessionemysql;

       import java.sql.Connection;
       import java.sql.DriverManager;
       import java.sql.ResultSet;
       import java.sql.SQLException;






       import android.app.Activity;
       import android.app.ProgressDialog;
       import android.os.AsyncTask;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.view.Menu;
       import android.view.MenuItem;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
       import android.widget.Button;
       import android.widget.Toast;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements               OnClickListener{
         Button bottone;
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         bottone = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         bottone.setOnClickListener(this);
    
    



}




          class ConnectAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

          String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prova";
          String user = "root";
          String password = "my_psw";

       
          Connection connection = null;
          try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
           } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Driver non caricato");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Errore con url e credenziali!");
            
        }

        if(connection!= null)
        {System.out.println("Connessione riuscita!");}
        return null;}
    
         }



        public void connectToDB(View view)
        {
         ConnectAsync task = new ConnectAsync();
       task.execute();







               }



              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
               connectToDB(v);

             }



                }
```

I also put the logcat here:

```
04-30 06:25:17.670: W/EGL_emulation(1965): eglSurfaceAttrib not     implemented
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965): com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965): The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1038)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:338)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2237)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.example.testconnessionemysql.MainActivity$ConnectAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:55)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.example.testconnessionemysql.MainActivity$ConnectAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:576)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:664)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at java.net.Socket.setTcpNoDelay(Socket.java:530)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.configureSocket(StandardSocketFactory.java:134)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:205)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:297)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     ... 20 more
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:561)
04-30 06:25:22.150: W/System.err(1965):     ... 26 more
04-30 06:25:22.150: I/System.out(1965): Errore con url e credenziali!
```

As you can see from the logcat,it catches an SQLException and prints out the message I wrote in the code,so I think there's a problem with the database connectivity.
I use MYSQL Workbench to handle this database,i also granted the root user the privilege to access from every IP address,and i also edited the my.ini MySQL configuration file in this way:

```
[mysqld]
...

bind-address    = *
#skip-networking
...
```

I use MySQL Server 5.6,and I used mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar as JDBC driver.
As I previously said,I was able to connect to another MySQL database on the internet using the same code without errors...I just can't find what's going on with my database.

I know that JDBC database connection in Android isn't the best solution,but I wanted to practice this way before moving to something more efficient (like JSON and web services).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no mysql database in android phone.Making connection with mysql through jdbc works when you make a simple Java Project(not an android project) and you have mysql installed on laptop and you are storing data in the mysql database.
Here what happens is when you run your app the app goes to mobile and mysql is in laptop ,there is no mysql in android phone.in other words no way android phone can store data in database which is in laptop.
If you want to store data in android phone ,you can use SQLite which is a local database in android phones...Your app stores data in Sqlite and retrieves it when needed.

Here is a good tutorial for android database connectivity ---http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: i think this is not the point:as i said in my post,i was able to connect through JDBC to a MySQL database located on the internet without problems.I don't think that I need a database on my phone to get connected to another database

Answer (score 0):

You not must be use "/localhost:3306". Instead you must be use the ip address of your local machine (NO 127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use localhost, since the Android application can not connect with the db server on your computer.

There are ways through which you could do it if you're using locally, you could setup wamp server to use it in your connected mobile device by watching some tutorials on YouTube.

If you're still unable to do just use a free MySQL server available on internet for learning or testing purposes.